# Is it possible to invert clock polarity from command line?

Tags: linux, embedded, screen, clock

I have an embedded system that is made of a linux (kernel 2.6), and a display screen. The CPU-module used is a stamp9261 by Taskit. Here is the constructor documentation of the Linux : https://www.taskit.de/media/pdf/a0/f9/03/standard_starterkit_stamp9261_64f64r_linux_guide_t4260578790864.pdf

After changing the screen of the system, I have some display issues on the screen. According to the new screen datasheet, I have to invert the polarity of the clock signal.

I would like to know if it is possible to **invert clock polarity directly from command line** ?

I already searched for information on that clock in the system but I didn't learn much :

`# cat /sys/devices/system/clocksource/clocksource0/current_clocksource`
returns :

```
jiffies
```

**EDIT:**

I also searched for the display drivers, but the only drivers I found are

```
# find / -name *.ko
/lib/modules/2.6.22-taskit3/kernel/drivers/char/progFpga_aps600.ko
/lib/modules/2.6.22-taskit3/kernel/drivers/scsi/scsi_wait_scan.ko
/lib/modules/2.6.22-taskit3/kernel/drivers/input/misc/panelcard-knob.ko
/lib/modules/2.6.22-taskit3/kernel/drivers/input/keyboard/at91-matrix.ko
```

None of them seem to be related to display configuration.

I don't really know what to do with these information...

Thanks for your help.

Comment: As you can see from the `resolution` entries, you are on the wrong path. The value 10000000ns equals 10ms, which is the typical ticker period in a Linux system. What you found, is something like a "wall clock" of the OS, unrelated to the display driver. Not every term "clock" means the same thing.

Comment: The "clock" of your screen device is most probably something completely different. Please [edit] your question and provide model, links to relevant documents, and so on to explain the display issues. You might want to look for display driver configuration in your Linux in the meantime.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I edited my post with more info.

Comment: This was a good step, however, the mentioned "screen datasheet" is missing. The provided system guide mentions "lcd" and "display driver", might be a start point. -- And what specific "display issues" do you have? It could be anything, from a black screen over heavy flicker or blurriness to just a shift by one pixel. -- Did you consider to simply insert a fast hardware inverter in the clock line? -- Oh, and did you ask the manufacturer? They should be the experts.

Comment: If you want to do it from the command line it is not a programming question, so off-topic.  For clock polarity to be an issue, possibly this is an SPI display, and the clock it is referring to is the SCK?  Either way you need to modify, update, or configure  the device driver for the display.  A link to the _"new screen datasheet"_ you mention would be helpful.